# Programmatically easeOut UIImageView animationImages

Tags: ios, uiimageview

Is there a way to programmatically ease this animation besides manually adjusting the PNGs in image editing software? ie: Show an easeOut effect.  I've looked and haven't seen the answer on the web unless I'm using the wrong keywords to search for an answer.

```
NSMutableArray * images = [@[] mutableCopy];

for (int i = currentFrame; i <= maxFrame; i++) {

    NSString * imageString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"icon_introchart_%ld",i];
    UIImage * newImage = [UIImage imageNamed:imageString];
    [images addObject:newImage];

}

_introChart.animationImages = images;
_introChart.animationDuration = 2.0f;
_introChart.animationRepeatCount = 1;
```

EDITED -> but I'm still missing something:

```
CAKeyframeAnimation * animation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"contents"];
[animation setCalculationMode:kCAAnimationLinear];
animation.duration = 2.0;
animation.values = images;
animation.repeatCount = 1;
animation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut];
[animation setRemovedOnCompletion:YES];
[_introChart.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"contents"];

// _introChart.animationImages = images;
// _introChart.animationDuration = 2.0f;
//_introChart.animationRepeatCount = 1;
```

EDIT: I needed to supply CGImageRefs instead of UIImages for the "contents"...it works now.

```
UIImage * newImage = [UIImage imageNamed:imageString];
CGImageRef cgImage = [newImage CGImage];
[images addObject:(__bridge id)(cgImage)];
```

Comment: If only I had a nickel for every time I've forgotten to take the CGImage of a UIImage when setting a layer's contents...! :) The problem, of course, is that there is no compile-time or runtime error - but nothing actually _happens_ either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple UIImage animation is just that - simple. You can certainly do what you want to do, but you'll have to use real animation in order to get the sort of timing control you're asking for. The easiest way is probably to use a CAKeyframeAnimation, which gives you control over the timing of the "frames" of the animation.

Comment: Thanks matt, I knew there must be something and I probably wasn't using the right search words.  I'll check it out and report back :)

Comment: Works now! Thanks for pointing me in the right direction matt!